# How Can I Position a Clickable Image to Top of Browser in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Obviously I am a novice coder :( This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out.

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: none;
}
```

**BODY**

```
<div id="div" style="width:100%;height:1750px;z-index:1;">
<iframe src="mypage.html" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1750px" ALIGN="left">
</iframe>
</div>

<iframe src="http://www.website.com" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1750px" ALIGN="left">
</iframe>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#hover').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#div').show();
}).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#div').hide();
});
```

This webpage code displays the clickable image "30x1800clear.gif" at the top of the page that opens the "mypage.html" iframe content on hover and closes the ifame content on clicking the image. Which is exactly what I want it to do.

I want the image to stay fixed at the top of the page on scroll. If I try to use ANY styling at all, or surround the code in a DIV with any position styling the image disappears completely.

Can someone show me how to make the image stay fixed at the top of the browser window on scrolling the page?

Comment: can you please provide a jsfiddle or codepen example so we can see your code in action? Its hard to set up an exampel with your code since your iframe points to a relative url **mypage.html**

Answer (score 1):

add position is fixed to image tag. like this

```
 <img src="30x1800clear.gif" width="100%" height="20px" border="0" alt="" style="position: fixed;">
```

Comment: With my original code, adding ANY styling to the image made the image disappear completely. I'm not knowledgeable enough to know why.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. You have a div with id div. This is very confusing, so lets change the id to `mydiv`. In your css, you apply your `display:none` to `div`, so to all divs. I guess you want to apply it only to the div in question, so yo should change it to:

   ```
    #mydiv {
        display: none;
    }
   ```
2. You're mixing inline style and separate file for the same element, so let's combine everything into the css file:

   ```
   #mydiv {
      width:100%;
      height:1750px;
      z-index:1;
    }
   ```

   And the first line of your html becomes:
       `<div id="mydiv">`
3. Now, for the real question: You want to fix the position of the image to the top. Let's add this lines to the #mydiv css block:

   ```
   position: fixed;
   top: 4px; /* You can change this to any number of pixels you want, including 0 */
   left: 4px; /* Same thing */
   ```

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks for the suggestion to combine the CSS. I think that was my problem. I wish I would have posted this earlier and saved myself hours of time. Thanks for your input and being a part of my solution.

Comment: I just realized I was a bit confused when I wrote my answer; thaught the image to click was inside #mydiv.
I think your biggest problem was that your css "display: none" was set to "div", not "#div". It affected all divs in the page. But I am glad some refactoring saved it :).